# How can I use the locale service provided by Angular to set the tooltip label in Chart.js when using the tooltip call function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

```
    const config: any = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        localNumberPipe : this.localNumberPipe,
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [{
          minBarLength: 5,
          maxBarThickness: 50,
          label: 'Waterfall Chart',
          elements: {
            bar: {
              backgroundColor: this.color,
              borderColor: this.color,
            }
          },
          data: this.data,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderSkipped: false
        }]
      },
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
              context: {
                _this: this,
              },
              label: function (context) {
                var bar = JSON.parse(context.formattedValue);
                var label = [];
                if (bar) {
                  var l=  this.locale;
                  const diff = Number.parseFloat(bar[1]) - Number.parseFloat(bar[0]);
                  label.push('Difference: ' + formatNumber(diff, 'en-US', '1.0-0'));
                  label.push('Start: ' + formatNumber(bar[0], 'en-US', '1.0-0'));
                  label.push('End: ' + formatNumber(bar[1], 'en-US', '1.0-0'));
                }
                return label;
              }
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: [connectorLines]
    };
```

In the constructor I have this code where I am getting localy as 'an-US'

```
  constructor(private localeService: LocaleService) {
    this.localNumberPipe = new LocalNumberPipe(localeService);
    Chart.register(...registerables);
     **this.locale** = this.localeService.locale ;
    console.log(this.locale);
  }
```

but if I try to access this.locale in tooltip callback function it returns undefine. Is it something related to this scope? if so is any way to add locale in chart config as a property so I can access it in tooltip callback function.

In the developer console **this** return the tooltip details.

```
 label: function (context) {
                var bar = JSON.parse(context.formattedValue);
                debugger /// execute this at this stage
```

[image]

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `this` is the application when the `config` object is created, then you can use something on lines of

```js
tooltip: {
    callbacks: {
        label: (function(){
            const _this = this;
            return function(context){ // use _this.locale here
                var bar = JSON.parse(context.formattedValue);
                var label = [];
                if(bar){
                    var l = _this.locale;
                    const diff = Number.parseFloat(bar[1]) - Number.parseFloat(bar[0]);
                    label.push('Difference: ' + formatNumber(diff, 'en-US', '1.0-0'));
                    label.push('Start: ' + formatNumber(bar[0], 'en-US', '1.0-0'));
                    label.push('End: ' + formatNumber(bar[1], 'en-US', '1.0-0'));
                }
                return label;
            };
        })()
    }
}
```

or you can even bind the function to the outer `this`, as long as you don't get used to this method, because in general *one has to be very careful when binding a method to a foreign object*:

```js
   tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(context){
            //......... // use this.locale
            }.bind(this) // better avoid this
        }
    }
```

and a third option would be to use an arrow function, which inherits `this` from the outer scope:

```js
   tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
            label: (context) => {
                //......... // use this.locale
                return label;
            }
        }
    }
```